# Converting Mautic theme into bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, mautic

I want to convert Mautic Theme into bootstrap 4, in other words, currently the theme is done with bootstrpa 3.3.2, so if i start converting it to bootstrap 4 each class and each component structure it will take me maybe a month. If anyone know any faster way for me to do it?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.prepbootstrap.com/converter

use this converter for Bootstrap 3 to 4 Convert. its might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, it will help me a bit